# WCF class implementing multiple service contracts

Tags: c#, wcf, multiple-inheritance, servicecontract

I have a class `TestService` which implements two service contracts called `IService1` and `IService2`. But I'm facing a difficulty in implementation.

My code looks as follows:

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/ServiceModel/Service");
Uri baseAddress1 = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/ServiceModel/Service1");

ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService));

selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new WSHttpBinding(), baseAddress);
selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService2), new WSHttpBinding(), baseAddress1);

ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

selfHost.Open();
Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.ReadLine();

selfHost.Close();
```

I'm getting a run time error as:

> The HttpGetEnabled property of
>   ServiceMetadataBehavior is set to true
>   and the HttpGetUrl property is a
>   relative address, but there is no http
>   base address.  Either supply an http
>   base address or set HttpGetUrl to an
>   absolute address.

What can I do about it? Do I really need two separate endpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can fix it in two ways

1)

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/ServiceModel");
ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService), baseAdress);

selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new WSHttpBinding(), "Service");
selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService2), new WSHttpBinding(), "Service1");

ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
```

2)

```
ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
smb.HttpGetUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/ServiceModel");
selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to add an base address.
you still have two separated endpoints.

```
ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService), new Uri ("http://localhost:8080/ServiceModel"));
```